# What are the tradeoffs between importing the gutenberg packages from npm vs. using the WordPress global?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I have a WordPress plugin that registers several custom Gutenberg Blocks.

I've seen lots of block examples that begin by `impoort`ing various WordPress packages:

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
```

Importing the packages seems to be the recommended way to build Gutenberg Blocks.

The WordPress [Package Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/) says "packages are also available on npm if you want to bundle them in your code." and that all the packages are available under various `wp.` properties.

**What are the tradeoffs between using the npm packages vs using the global variables?**

I'm particularly concerned that if I use the packages I will end up with two copies of gutenberg that don't communicate.